# DirectX 10 SetRawValue is not working properly

Tags: c++, directx

I have two structs, one in c++ file and one in effect file. Both have three members, pos, speed and direction. Speed is float and pos and direction are vectors. When I send the struct from c++ file to effect file using SetRawValue and use the values, they are 0.

When I deleted one of members, everything worked properly and the values were not 0.

EDIT:
Here is the code:

C++ struct:

```
struct Player {
     D3DXVECTOR3 Pos;
     D3DXVECTOR3 Direction;
     float Speed;
}


void Initialize() {
     Player player;
     player.Pos = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     player.Direction = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.53543f, 0.1f);
     player.Speed = 5.0f;

     ID3D10EffectVariable *EffectPlayerVariable;
     EffectPlayerVariable = Shader->GetVariableByName("Player");

     EffectPlayerVariable->SetRawValue(&player, 0, sizeof(Player));
}
```

Effect File

```
struct Player {
     float3 Pos;
     float3 Direction;
     float Speed;
}
```

Pos and direction get their values, but speed does not.

Comment: You should provide a bit more context and perhaps a code sample. I infer that you are referring to a method on the Effects system for Direct3D 10.  Note that it is very similar to Effects for Direct3D 11, which is available as shared-source on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568).

Comment: Most probably the struct is not formatted in memory as you think it is.  Post the code and we'll try and tell you whats wrong!

Comment: Any ideas for this problem?